# How can I tell if the PL/SQL Profiler is running?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What's the best way to tell if the dbms_profiler package's PL/SQL profiler has been started (via some call to `dbms_profiler.start_profiler(...)` which has not yet been `dbms_profiler.stop_profiler(...)`-ed?

Comment: Try querying plsql_profiler_runs table.

Comment: @OldProgrammer All I see is information about past runs?

Comment: OK, I thought maybe it showed also the current runs.  Just a stab in the dark.  Not sure where else to look.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I just happened to view that table while a run was processing.  It turns out that assuming the data has been `.flush_profiler()`-ed, there will be a record with a `NULL` value in the `TOTAL_TIME` column.  I think checking for any rows like this will do the trick!